# Is `char _3 = 'c'` valid in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, variables, identifier

Considering, i have declared variable name as a numeric with underscore.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char _3 = 'c';
   printf("%c\n",_3);
}
```

I wonder, It's working fine in C and C++. So,is it valid?

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: @alk yes it is compile fine.

Comment: It's legal, but why would you do that? That's a useless name for a variable.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it shows no research effort. Searching "C valid variable names" gives the answer.

Comment: `_3` is a valid identifier in C and C++.   Problem is, it is a reserved identifier for use in the global namespace (C++) or for identifiers at file scope (C) - so code outside the implementation (including this example) which uses such identifiers has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter - This particular code doesn't have UB. Name hiding and resolution guarantees it.

Comment: Legal in this case, not in others. I would suggest simply never starting names with underscore and *never* use double underscore, then you don't have to worry about the specifics of the rules.

Comment: @alk code compiling is *useless* as a test of correctness. Lots of code with undefined behaviour compiles just fine but is never the less broken (and *will* sometimes blow up in your face).

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. You are asking two questions here which is strongly discouraged on stack overflow. Not that you should have asked at all, with 10k reps one can be expected to do show some research before asking and show that.

Comment: This is very basic, simple google search yielded the result what you seek for. Wondering someone even consider this as favorite question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All variable names must begin with a letter of the alphabet or an
underscore. So yes, it is valid, except if you place it on file scope. (Be careful with double underscore though, it is reserved for the compiler internal use)

Yet, I wouldn't recommend having variables with names like that, since it may be confusing for the reader.

From the C++ 2003 standard:

> #### 17.4.3.1.2 Global names [lib.global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.<sup>165</sup>
>
> <sup>165)</sup> Such names are also reserved in namespace ::std (17.4.3.1).

Answer (score 5):

It's valid in any scope other than global scope<sup>1</sup>.

C++17 - [n4659 / [lex.name]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name)

> In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++
>   implementations and shall not be used otherwise; no diagnostic is
>   required.
>
> - **Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace**.

The standard library actually has an example of it in namespace scope, inherited from `boost`: The placeholders for `std::bind`.

And C has similar phrasing:

C11 - [n1570 / 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)

> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its
>   associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers
>   listed in its associated future library directions subclause and
>   identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as
>   file scope identifiers.
>
> - **All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag
>     name spaces.**

Though the choice of scopes is more limited.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Not a normative term, just a bastardization of the terms used by the two standards.</sub>

Comment: `_c` is not in the global name-space, though.

Comment: @Olaf - `_c`? Not sure I follow you on this

Comment: Whatever it is in C++, C has nothing like a "global name-space" as the snippet from the standard show. And `_c` is at function/block scope here. For C++, it is similar, just more generally phrased.

Comment: @Olaf - I've made a clear separation of the two quotes, and explicitly marked the bastardized term. So I really have no clue what issue you are pointing at